# Hey I'm unable to install pyinstaller properly

Tags: pyinstaller

Hey I tried running these:
1)pip uninstall pyinstaller
2)pip install pyinstaller
3)pyinstaller
but then the error starts

Please help me I'm trying to compile py files to exe the first time`enter code here`

```
E:\Hacking\TEsting malwarres>pip uninstall pyinstaller
Found existing installation: pyinstaller 4.1
Uninstalling pyinstaller-4.1:
  Would remove:
    c:\users\admin\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\scripts\pyi-archive_viewer.exe
    c:\users\admin\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\scripts\pyi-bindepend.exe
    c:\users\admin\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\scripts\pyi-grab_version.exe
    c:\users\admin\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\scripts\pyi-makespec.exe
    c:\users\admin\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\scripts\pyi-set_version.exe
    c:\users\admin\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\scripts\pyinstaller.exe
    c:\users\admin\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages\pyinstaller-4.1.dist-info\*
    c:\users\admin\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages\pyinstaller\*
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled pyinstaller-4.1

E:\Hacking\TEsting malwarres>pip install pyinstaller
Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached pyinstaller-4.1-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pefile>=2017.8.1 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2019.4.18)
Requirement already satisfied: altgraph in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.17)
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller-hooks-contrib>=2020.6 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2020.10)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\program files\windowsapps\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (47.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32-ctypes>=0.2.0 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pefile>=2017.8.1->pyinstaller) (0.18.2)
Installing collected packages: pyinstaller
  WARNING: The scripts pyi-archive_viewer.exe, pyi-bindepend.exe, pyi-grab_version.exe, pyi-makespec.exe, pyi-set_version.exe and pyinstaller.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed pyinstaller-4.1

E:\Hacking\TEsting malwarres>pyinstaller
'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall python and pyinstaller then run it.

By the way, `pyinstaller` by itself will not work, It just lists commands.

Do `pyinstaller filename.py` for it to work.